# Is it possible to use tomcat 7.0.20 within eclipse indigo?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, tomcat7

While installing the new eclipse indigo IDE I've tried to setup the tomcat server previously downloaded from Apache web site (tomcat 7.0.20) with no success. When I fill the tomcat directory in the form it causes an error to appear saying the version I chosen is not valid. It also suggests to download the tomcat version 7.0.12. Why? Is there a way to use the latest version of tomcat with indigo eclipse? Is there a compatibility problem with version newer than 7.0.12?

I downloaded the windows 64bit version of tomcat 7.0.20, but using an old 7.0.16 I already had the result is the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the invalid version message is a bit misleading; it just doesn't like something about the installation. Anyway, here's what worked for me, using Ubuntu 11.10, eclipse Indigo JavaEE SR2, tomcat 7.0.21.

I have a standalone tomcat installation as per the standard ubuntu tomcat7 package. I used tomcat7-instance-create to create a separate tomcat instance for eclipse:

```
$ tomcat7-instance-create -p 8000 -c 8003 ~/dev/eclipse/tomcat
```

This required a few additions to keep eclipse happy

```
$ cd ~/dev/eclipse/tomcat
$ ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/lib
$ ln -s /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/policy.d/03catalina.policy conf/catalina.policy
$ ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar bin/bootstrap.jar
$ ln -s /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar bin/tomcat-juli.jar
$ tree
.
├── bin
│   ├── bootstrap.jar -> /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/bootstrap.jar
│   ├── setenv.sh
│   ├── shutdown.sh
│   ├── startup.sh
│   └── tomcat-juli.jar -> /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
├── conf
│   ├── catalina.policy -> /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/policy.d/03catalina.policy
│   ├── catalina.properties
│   ├── context.xml
│   ├── logging.properties
│   ├── server.xml
│   ├── tomcat-users.xml
│   └── web.xml
├── lib -> /usr/share/tomcat7/lib
├── logs
├── temp
├── webapps
└── work
```

Then just add a new runtime environment and server as normal, and it's all good!

HTH,

Comment: Confirm: This is still up to date for Ubuntu 12.10. with Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 4):

I found this page amazingly helpful

[Tomcat 7 with Eclipse](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/tomcat-7-with-eclipse.html)

Also a lot of my problems went away when I switched from Elipse Classic to Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.

Comment: This fixed a problem with tomcat when I uninstalled the Mongrel Tomcat plugin.  Many thanks for posting the link!

Answer (score 2):

Launch eclipse, goto Window / Preferences / Server / Runtime and add Tomcat installation directory. This registers Tomcat with Eclipse Indigo.

It seems that there is no Helios version for Mac, only Indigo.

Answer (score 1):

I've downloaded Eclipse for Java EE developers (Eclipse Indigo 64 bit, running JDK 1.6.0_25 64 bit) and I've successfully added Tomcat 7.0.20 as a server (and Tomcat 7.0 for Windows). Unless you specify the error logs, there is no problem whatsoever.

Comment: If you don't start out downloading Eclipse for J2EE, then you have to add the J2EE functionality afterwards, including JST modules which enable you to create the server runtimes.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can't use an installed copy, and that's what it sounds like you've got.  Installed copies usually have their libraries and configuration files scattered in unpredictable ways that make it difficult/impossible for Eclipse to properly launch the server itself.  You may not need 7.0.12, but you will need to use the zip/tar.gz download.

Comment: Thanks Nitind but I've just downloaded the zip file and unzip it in a directory - no istallation on windows. Eclipse instead forced me to use only the 7.0.12 version (to be downloaded from eclipse). That's strange.

Comment: What did you use to unzip it?  Was the directory structure in the zip file extracted properly?

Comment: Yes, the unzip is correct. Helios is able to set-up tomcat from the unzipped directory without problem.

Comment: As a workaround I found out that setting-up tomcat using helios in a workspace and open that workspace using indigo everithing is working fine!! But why?

Answer (score 0):

Following on the advice to add some symbolic links, I needed to due the following to match my synaptic tomcat7 /usr/share/tomcat7 to eclipse indigo's requirements.

Install tomcat7 using synaptic.
Add a tomcat7 server using the eclipse wizard (I let eclipse download it into  /home/me/tomcat7 ).
Compare the folder structure of /usr/share/tomcat7 and /home/me/tomcat7.
Add any symbolic links from /var/lib/tomcat7 to /usr/share/tomcat7 to match /home/tomcat7 .
Copy the 'missing' jars in /home/me/tomcat7/bin and /home/me/tomcat7/lib to their respective locations in /usr/share/tomcat7 .

In short - let the wizard setup the server, then see what you can do to adulterate your synaptic configuration to match the eclipse needs ;-)  Worked for me in Ubuntu 12.04 oracle java 1.7.