# Ubuntu Eclipse Tomcat could not load the Tomcat server configuration

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, ubuntu

I'm trying to create a dynamic web application on Ubuntu(14.04), using eclipse Java EE(4.5.1), and the Tomcat is v7.0
When I tried to run the server, it prompted "Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config".
I've already copied all files of /etc/tomcat7 to /workspace/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config, before I tried to run the server.
And I've also assigned the tomcat7 group to my user by running:

```
sudo adduser loh tomcat7
```

Besides, I can't find folder *tomcat_7_home* and subfolder *config* as other answers suggest
I only found /etc/tomcat7, and copied all files and subfolders to /workspace/Servers/Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost-config
Anyone has clue what is going on?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you create the server in Eclipse ?

Comment: Through WTP.  Menu: Window - Preferences - Server - Runtime Environments - Add.  And then add a new server on the Servers tab.  I've already got it done, I'll post it later!

Comment: Can you see a project 'Servers' in the explorer ?

Comment: Tomcat 8 and the latest Eclipse (Mars) still works for me with the standard `apt-get` package install and `tomcat-instance-create`... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7171244/is-it-possible-to-use-tomcat-7-0-20-within-eclipse-indigo/9961433#9961433. Cheers.

Comment: @Barney Thanks Barney. For some strange reasons, I couldn't achieve it through 'apt-get' command. But that wouldn't be my most concern right now XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## I've finally started local server from eclipse on Ubuntu.

#### Here is my solution:

*NOTE: I assume you've already installed WTP on eclipse*
Step 1: Download tomcat(I downloaded tomcat 8 in my case), download the tar.gz file from http://tomcat.apache.org/
Do NOT use command line, `sudo apt-get install tomcat7`, I ran into problem through this approach. Correct me if I'm wrong.
Step 2: Extract tar.gz file to the directory: /opt
navigate to the downloads directory, and use command line: `sudo tar zxvf filename.tar.gz -C /opt`
Step 3: Configure WTP on eclipse
select Windows -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments;
press Add…;
select Apache Tomcat v8.0(your version);
enter /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.30(your directory) into the “Tomcat installation directory” field;
press Ok;
Step 4: Create a dynamic web project. Just follow the instruction, it's very simple.
*Remember to check "generate the web.xml"*
Step 5: Add a new server.
click on server tab, and click on the underline text.
enter /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.30(your directory) into the “Tomcat installation directory” field;
press Next;
select your project on the left pane under “Available” and press add to move it to the right pane under “Configured”;
press Finish”;
**If you run into trouble enter the server name, go get the permission of the directory: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.30(your directory)**
use command line: `sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.30(your directory)`
Step 6: Start the server by click on the button, the one on the right side of the debug button

Reference link: http://gridlab.dimes.unical.it/lackovic/eclipse-tomcat-ubuntu-jersey/

Comment: Creating runtime environment first (separately) and server after solved my problem too, thanks for the guide!